# Preserve Date format after APPLY

Tags: r

I have been trying to convert a character vector into a vector of dates. I have a vector called "dates" which is character. I used a function from the "lubridate" package to convert it into POSIXct format. When I individually convert each an every element to POSIXct and bind them using c(), I get the desired output, i.e "dates_final".

When I try to use the apply function to get the same output, it gives me a numeric vector. Is there a way to preserve the format while applying the function?

This is just an example. In my original dataset, the dates are in different formats as characters, I have written a custom function that detects formats for each an every type of date and parses them, and outputs POSIXct format. If the dates were in the same format in the whole data it would not have been a problem.

The data set has millions of records. I cannot possibly use a loop.

```
library(lubridate)

dates <- c("01-05-2015 00:10","01-05-2015 00:15",
            "01-05-2015 00:15","01-05-2015 00:42")

dates_actaul_1 <- dmy_hm(dates[1])
dates_actaul_2 <- dmy_hm(dates[2])
dates_actaul_3 <- dmy_hm(dates[3])
dates_actaul_4 <- dmy_hm(dates[4])

dates_final <- c(dates_actaul_1,dates_actaul_2,dates_actaul_3,dates_actaul_4)
dates_final
[1] "2015-05-01 05:40:00 IST" "2015-05-01 05:45:00 IST"
[3] "2015-05-01 05:45:00 IST" "2015-05-01 06:12:00 IST"

dates_applied <- apply(X = data.frame(dates),MARGIN = 1,FUN = dmy_hm)
dates_applied
[1] 1430439000 1430439300 1430439300 1430440920
```

Comment: This works without any `apply`  `dmy_hm(dates)`  If you need to change the `apply` output to POSIXct `as.POSIXct(dates_applied, origin='1970-01-01', tz='UTC')`

Comment: have made a few edits to the post. The problem is the output of apply.

Comment: Have you tried converting to `as.POSIXct` with `origin` specified as in the comments

Comment: ok, specifying the origin did it. Works fine now. why is it 1970? if you dont mind? i did not know that.

Comment: If the dataset have million of rows, it is better to use the vectorized approach i.e. `dmy_hm(dates)` instead of looping.

Comment: As I said, the format keeps on changing, some are strings with format "Mar 05 12:30:00 2015", some with "01-05-2015 00:10", my custom function detects the required format as parses it, but the output was the issue. I still cant fathom why it is 1970

Comment: You could read some info from `?as.POSIXct`.  Also, you can use `guess_formats` from lubridate if you know the possible date formats

Comment: It is far more complicated than it sounds. Anyway, thanks for the help. Should I delete the question? or put in an answer?

Comment: You can add that as an answer